# Above code gives error Invalid character constant in selenium with java

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, underscore-java

`String wb = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='gb_h gb_i']/a")).getAttribute('href');`

Above code gives error `Invalid character constant`
I want to fetch `href` from html code using java

Comment: Did my answer resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should change `getAttribute('href')` to `getAttribute("href")` so it should be
`String wb = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='gb_h gb_i']/a")).getAttribute("href");`
`getAttribute()` method receives `String`.
In Java `String` is defined by `" "` while `Character` is defined by `' '`